# recursive task that does its work not completely

Tags: java, recursion

I have tried to create a recursive task that divides a set of elements into smaller pieces and runs a series of math works on them, say numerically integration, then tries to use separate results for each element. but it seems that an error occurs before the pool does its works completely. my code tries to reach the elements that are not yet processed. 
could you please help me with this?

```
public void ComputeStiffnessMatrix(DataScanner DS){

    ans=new double [2*(DS.getXarray().length)][2*(DS.getXarray().length)];

    int nelels=((DS.getNelKsi())*(DS.getNelEta()));

    ArrayList<ElementStiffness> elsm=new ArrayList<>();

    StiffnessMatrix SM=new StiffnessMatrix(elsm,DS,0,(nelels-1));
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    System.out.println("Stiffness Matrix Computation...");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pool.invoke(SM);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Stiffness Matrix Computation took " + (endTime - startTime) +  " milliseconds.");
    System.out.println("Arranging into an array...");
    long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();



    try {
        ArrayList<ElementStiffness> kk=(ArrayList<ElementStiffness>) SM.get();

        for (int el=0;el<nelels;el++){

            ElementStiffness pp=kk.get(el);
            System.out.println("EL NO."+el);
            double vals[][]=pp.getStiffnessMatrix();
            int sup[]=pp.getControlpointsSupport();

            for (int i=0;i<sup.length;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<sup.length;j++){
                    ans[(2*sup[i])+0][(2*sup[j])+0]=ans[(2*sup[i])+0][(2*sup[j])+0]+vals[(2*i)+0][(2*j)+0];
                    ans[(2*sup[i])+0][(2*sup[j])+1]=ans[(2*sup[i])+0][(2*sup[j])+1]+vals[(2*i)+0][(2*j)+1];
                    ans[(2*sup[i])+1][(2*sup[j])+0]=ans[(2*sup[i])+1][(2*sup[j])+0]+vals[(2*i)+1][(2*j)+0];
                    ans[(2*sup[i])+1][(2*sup[j])+1]=ans[(2*sup[i])+1][(2*sup[j])+1]+vals[(2*i)+1][(2*j)+1];
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IGATest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Stiffness Matrix rearrangement took " + (endTime2 - startTime2) +  " milliseconds.");

    try{
        FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("stifmat.tmp");
        ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        os.writeObject(ans);
        os.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ans=null;


}
```

And the siffnessmatrix class:

public class StiffnessMatrix  extends RecursiveTask {

```
private final int min;
private final int max;
private final DataScanner ds;
ArrayList<ElementStiffness> elsm;

public StiffnessMatrix (ArrayList<ElementStiffness> elsm,DataScanner DS,int min, int max){

    this.ds=DS;
    this.min=min;
    this.max=max;
    this.elsm=elsm;
}



protected void compdir(){

    for (int i=min;i<=max;i++){
        double[] elsp=ds.getElementSpan(i);
        Element el=new Element(ds,((elsp[0]+elsp[1])*0.5),((elsp[2]+elsp[3])*0.5));
        ElementStiffness els=new ElementStiffness(ds,el);
        elsm.add(els);
    }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList <ElementStiffness> compute(){


    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    if (max-min<processors) {      
        compdir();
    } else {
        int center = min + (max - min) / 2;
        invokeAll(new StiffnessMatrix(elsm,ds, min, center) , new StiffnessMatrix(elsm, ds, center+1, max));

    }     
    return elsm;
}
```

}

Comment: That said, show us the error, and show us your `StiffnessMatrix` (heh heh). It sounds like you are either not properly waiting for the tasks to complete, or you are not starting all of the tasks you think you are starting (some debug printouts will help you determine which of those is the case).

Comment: @JasonC Yes exactly. :D

Comment: @JasonC You know, how should I wait for tasks t be complete?

Comment: @JasonC What I meant to do was to ensure hat all the elements are completely processed. I believe the "pool.invoke(SM)" part completely ensures the completeion. doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you're right, `invoke` waits for the tasks to complete, sorry. So perhaps you aren't scheduling all the tasks you think you are. That's why you really need to show us the code for `StiffnessMatrix`; if you have an error in your `ForkJoinTask` implementation, it could cause any number of problems.

Comment: @JasonC As you have kindly asked, I will add the class "StiffnessMatrix" to the body of the question.
thank you for your help dear Jason.